# Building a live wallpaper

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas, live-wallpaper

I'm stuck. I'm trying to build a live wallpaper using frames. The code I'm using is not working. The live wallpaper doesn't movie through the frames. It only shows the last frame. What should I do to this code to get it to move through its frames? A array method, if so how would I set up a array of images in this code?

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;

import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class WallpaperSer extends WallpaperService {

    public void onCreate() 

    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public Engine onCreateEngine() 
    {
        return new WallpaperSerEngine();
    }

    class WallpaperSerEngine extends Engine 
    {
        public Bitmap image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9,image10,
        image11, image12, image13, image14, image15, image16, image17, image18, image19,image20;

        WallpaperSerEngine() 
        {       
                image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and1);
                image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and2);
                image3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and3); 
                image4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and4);
                image5 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and5);
                image6 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and6);
                image7 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and7);
                image8 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and8);
                image9 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and9);
                image10 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and10);
                image11 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and11);
                image12 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and12);
                image13 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and13); 
                image14 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and14);
                image15 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and15);
                image16 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and16);
                image17 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and17);
                image18 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and18);
                image19 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and19);
                image20 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and20);
        }

        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) 
        {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        }

        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) 
        {
            drawFrame();

        }

        void drawFrame() 
        {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;
            try 
            {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null) 
                {              
                     c.drawBitmap(image1, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image2, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image3, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image4, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image5, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image6, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image7, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image8, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image9, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image10, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image11, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image12, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image13, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image14, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image15, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image16, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image17, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image18, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image19, 0, 0, null);
                     c.drawBitmap(image20, 0, 0, null);
                }
            } finally 
            {
                if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This Is a edit To my code. Not the solution....

```
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;

 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

 import android.graphics.Canvas;

 import android.os.Handler;

 import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;

 import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

 public class WallpaperSer extends WallpaperService {

int incrementer=0;
Bitmap bmps[]=new Bitmap[10];

public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
}

public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
}

public Engine onCreateEngine() 
{
    return new WallpaperSerEngine();
}

class WallpaperSerEngine extends Engine 
{

    int res[]={R.drawable.and1,R.drawable.and2,R.drawable.and3,R.drawable.and4,R.drawable.and5,R.drawable.and6,R.drawable.and7,R.drawable.and8,R.drawable.and9,R.drawable.and10};
    WallpaperSerEngine() 
    {  
          for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
              {
                    bmps[i]= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),res[i]);                     
               }
    }
}

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
     private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                  drawFrame();
                  handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);

                  handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 200);
            }

        };
        void drawFrame() 
        {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;
            try 
            {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null) 
                {              

                     c.drawBitmap(bmps[incrementer], 0, 0, null);

                    incrementer=(incrementer==10)?0 : incrementer+1; 
                }
            } finally 
            {
                if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

        private SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are drawing all frames at the same time...

Comment: Hi. I have answered your question. Take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register a Handler and make use of some threads.

But first of all add a global int like this,

int incrementer=0;

See this modified code of yours.

**1)** Inside your  `WallpaperSerEngine` class, create a Handler like this,

```
 private final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

**2)** Similarly add a **Runnable** inside `WallpaperSerEngine` class and call your   `drawFrame()`,

```
 private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

              drawFrame();              
        }

    };
```

**3)**  Add the below lines to the bottom of your drawFrame() to ensure that your runnable is called on a certain time interval to draw the frames,

```
                handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);

        handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 200); //delay milliseconds 200. Change it for your need.
```

**4)** Now change your **drawFrame()** method. YOu cannot do it in this way. You have to make use of some Bitmap Arrays. This is critical. Kindle follow the below steps clearly.

**5)** Instead of declaring variable for each bitmap, put it in a Bitmap array .

```
Bitmap bmps[]=new Bitmap[10]; // assign its size based on your need. I just need 10 for demo.
```

**6)** Now declare a int array for your Drawable resources.

```
   int res[]={R.drawable.and1,R.drawable.and2,R.drawable.and3,R.drawable.and4,R.drawable.and5,R.drawable.and6,R.drawable.and7,R.drawable.and8,R.drawable.and9,R.drawable.and10};
```

**7)** Now change your `WallpaperSerEngine()` like this.

```
WallpaperSerEngine() 
        {  
              for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
                  {
                        bmps[i]= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),res[i]);                     
                   }
        }
```

**8)** And now finally a little bit modification in your **drawFrame()**,

```
void drawFrame() 
        {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;
            try 
            {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null) 
                {              

                     c.drawBitmap(bmps[incrementer], 0, 0, null);

                    incrementer=(incrementer==10)?0 : incrementer+1; 
                }
            } finally 
            {
                if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

That's it. You should be seeing your frames now. And accept it if this is helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time fallowing. I'm not fully sure where to place these codes... When you say insert this into your WallpaperSerEngine class, do you mean as a variable? or below where I have image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and1); etc. I'm sorry! I'm new to this. But I am dedicated to learn...

Comment: you have to remove everything from the constructor and add only that for loop there.Comment for further help. No probelms

Comment: Thanks. If you look above below my original question, I placed how think i should insert the code... This doesn't work, so I must be doing it wronge. I get a force close...

Comment: There's a lot. 1 is FATAL EXCEPTION: main. Another is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions. Another at my package name.WallpaperSer$WallpaperSerEngine.<init>(WallpaperSer.java:48) There's about 15 in all errors...

Comment: remove i<=10 and change to i<10 in constructor for loop. And inside drawFrame method, change     incrementer=(incrementer==10)?0 : incrementer+1;  to     incrementer=(incrementer==9)?0 : incrementer+1;

Comment: Ok... Its no longer force closing. It says "loading live wallpaper" but nothing loads. Maybe it has something to do with my images? Maybe to large to load?

Comment: Also under drawRunner in the line of code, "private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable()" there's a yellow line under it.

Comment: then try printing Log in your methods and check whether the control flows correctly through the methods.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that... I'm sorry bro... I'm really putting a chink in your armor... i know you're trying to help me and earn you points... But I'm most likely going to have to figure out a new approach...

Comment: I'm going to mess with it more tomorrow... If I get it running, I'll let you know...

Comment: Won't decoding 10 bitmaps at once through OutOfMemoryException?